# Oracle forms search filter

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, oracleforms

I have created datablock with product information. I want to search by product Id; for that I have created trigger an on search button.

```
declare 
    x varchar2(20);
begin

    X:= 'description=' || chr(39) || :inverntory.s || chr(39) ;

    set_block_property('search', default_where, x);

    execute_query ;

end;
```

when I run the form it gives me this error:

```
FRM 40735 when button pressed trigger raised unhanded exception ora-06502
```

what is wrong with the datatype, or...?

Comment: Data type or what...?

Comment: i search this error it is because of datatype. Please guide me to solve problem

Comment: That last sentence you wrote ended on the word 'or'. Was there something else you were going to write afterwards?

Comment: provide full trigger code. What datatype is X? It is probably to short. How long is it? What datatype is it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed first line of code... X is propably too short. Make it Varchar2(2000)

Comment: I changed X value and tried to search but it gives message  record 1/1 but data is not displaying in fields still

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data block variable you don't have to concatenate it into WHERE string. This is bad practice. And you also then have a pressure on X length. Just bind it like this:

```
declare 
    x varchar2(100);
begin
    X:= 'description=:inverntory.s';
    set_block_property('search', default_where, x);
    execute_query ;
end;
```